# How to keep chat popup opened while visiting different pages of website?

Tags: javascript

I have a popup for chat defined at front end of website.This is the link from where i have directly used source code for chat popup https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup_chat.asp .

```js
  function openForm() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function closeForm() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<!--This is the html of chat popup-->

    <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
      <form action="" class="form-container">
        <h1>Chat</h1>
    
        <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
        <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required><textarea>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
       
      </form>
     </div>
```

I have pasted the html and js code of this popup in index.html and I am triggering to show this chat popup as soon as some conditions are satisfied:

```
if(some_condition)
 {
   $(".chot-popup").show();
 }
```

But the problem is as soon as i visit any other page of my website, popup vanishes. I want that popup should stay there and changing pages should have no effect on popup.Otherwise how can i continue the chat if popup will vanish on changing the page.

**P.S: I will implement this chatting functionality using django-channels and its websockets feature**

Comment: You can't unless you have a single page app. Otherwise you need to initialize your chat app on each new page load and implement some state saving either on server or localStorage

Comment: Set a cookie to *save* the state of the chat ?

Comment: What about the chat session? Opening other page will again reload and run the code and chat session will be lost @Cid

Comment: You can get cookie or session or use localStorage with JavaScript, for example : `localStorage.setItem('isChatOpen', <bool>);` and on each page check with JavaScript : `localStorage.getItem('isChatOpen')`. In function of `isChatOpen` value, display or not the chat box.

Comment: May you guys please provide me some link about how to do this as per your approach. Thanks @Cid

Comment: @AshokKumar The doc for `localStorage` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Tell me if it works, if it did, I'll put it as answer for future readers. Glad it did helped you if it did.

Comment: googling js and cookies may help finding the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) :)

Comment: @KévinHuang I will try to achieve this using your approach and given documentation and if it would work out i will definitely let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your `localStorage` and get it in your if condition

```
 function openForm() {
      localStorage.setItem("chatVisible", "True");
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeForm() {
      localStorage.setItem("chatVisible", "False");
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    }
```

in your page load use `localStorage.getitem`

```
var chat = localStorage.getItem("chatVisible");
if(chat == "True")
 {
   $(".chot-popup").show();
 }
 else{
   $(".chot-popup").hide();
 }
```

Comment: I am really sorry that i am accepting this answer very late but i got engaged in other task hence could not  implement your solution.But now i have implemented your idea and it works flawlessly@UdhayTitus

Answer (score 1):

I did copy the chat pop up style from your tutorial : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup_chat.asp

What I did was to add a `localStorage` to check in each page if the chat box was open or not and then display it in function of `localStorage` value.

Documentation of `localStorage` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You can also use cookie, here's the documentation for it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

```js
function openForm() {
  //localStorage.setItem("isChatOpen", true);
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  //localStorage.setItem("isChatOpen", false);
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

/*if(localStorage.getItem("isChatOpen") === true){
   document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
} else {
   document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}*/
```

```css
/* Button used to open the chat form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}

/* The popup chat - hidden by default */
.chat-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width textarea */
.form-container textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 200px;
}

/* When the textarea gets focus, do something */
.form-container textarea:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/send button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Chat</button>

<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Chat</h1>

    <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
    <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Just remove the comments in my fiddle, localStorage doesn't work with sandbox.

Comment: Same idea has been proposed by UdhayTitus earlier than you so i have to accept his solution as answer. Thanks a lot you took time to solve my problem. @Bambou